# How to find max connections used by memcached?

Tags: linux, memcached

In our LAMP application we have increased the max connection value for memcached to very high to avoid error for max connection we were having. Now we want to set appropriate value to max connections for memcached. Is there a way to find the maximum connections used by memcached during the period it has been working?

I know how to find connections used by memcached at a given moment.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to install [memcache-top](http://code.google.com/p/memcache-top/) which will give you number of connections as well as a wealth of other information for your memcache instances.

Answer (score 1):

was looking into this for some fun metrics, so I guess a little late than never, telnet to the box and run the following command:
stats settings

Nice and easy to parse for a quick percent of connections used in conjunction with the stats result from current connections - (curr_connections / maxconns )*100